# The CGLIB enhancement can not work after I introduce the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, caffeine-cache

The `@Cacheable` and `@CachePut` annotation works well before I introduce the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

It is the bean with `@Cacheable` and `@CachePut` annotation:

```
@Service
public class BasicAuthRestTemplate {


    @Cacheable(value = "restTemplate", key = "#email")
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(String email) {

        return null;
    }

    @CachePut(value = "restTemplate", key = "#email")
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(String email, String password) {

        return new RestTemplateBuilder().basicAuthentication(email, password).build();
    }
}
```

The following is the launched log info, That is to say, when the system according to the specific conditions, decides to use the CglibAutoProxyConfiguration, the CGLIB function ceases to work

```
the bean can not be enhanced by CGLIB:

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration.CglibAutoProxyConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)


   AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)    
      
================================================================================================      
      
the bean can be enhaced by CGLIB :


   AopAutoConfiguration.ClassProxyingConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      
      
   AopAutoConfiguration.AspectJAutoProxyingConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.aspectj.weaver.Advice' (OnClassCondition)
```

If I exclude the `aspectjweaver` in the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency, it will work well as before. So I can confirm that adding this dependency caused CGLIB functionality to fail.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

### 2023/05/31 update

In the case of not using the aspect weaver dependency,  initialize the bean is completed, and then call the postprocessor (`postProcessAfterInitialization`), and the bean that can find `spring framework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor` can be proxied

[Breakpoint screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh722.png)

### 2023/06/01 update

Perhaps the reason for this error is not the dependency on aspect weaver, because I also added a JPA dependency in a previous copy of this project, and it works just fine. Maybe this error is caused by other reasons, but I can't find the answer on the Internet, so I just keep looking at the source code

When using the aspect weaver, the `org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor`can be found is the key to get the proxied bean, the reason why the `InternalCacheAdvisor` can not be added to the list of eligible advisors is that the result of 'this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(name)' is true.

[the result of 'this.beanFactory.isCurrentlyInCreation(name)' is true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJfq1.png)

### 2023/06/02 update

I found the same issue in Spring's GitHub : [Advisor silently skipped if it is currently in creation [SPR-10430]](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/15063)

There is a solution that uses @Lazy:

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
private BasicAuthRestTemplate basicAuthRestTemplate;
```

But I believe there is room for improvement at the framework level.